# Is there an efficient one-liner to run a function for each group of factor in a data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to solve this problem as effienctly as possible and I don't know if what I got till now is the best option. Do you guys have any alternative?

The output I get is exactly what I want (actually it would be nice if the column names wouldn't repeat for each function), but I am wondering whether I can find a better way to do it (where I do the for loops).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to do this in once go and then save the outputs. I believe this aligns with what you need, please let me know otherwise :)

```
# try converting to long format, and then using the by conditions to get 
# aggregate views
# melt is used to convert wide to long, splitting columns over combinations 
# of the id.vars
tr2 <- melt(tr, id.vars = c("industry", "country"))
# do the aggregations, at (1) industry level, (2) at country level
sol1 <- tr2[, .(N=.N, min=min(value), max=max(value)), by=.(variable, industry)]
sol2 <- tr2[, .(N=.N, min=min(value), max=max(value)), by=.(variable, country)]
# sense check
sol1[]
sol2[]
```

edit: sorry forgot the `N` column. `.N` is a data.table syntax for counts

edit: comment...

```
SummaryStat <- function(table, ids){ 
  table <- melt(table, id.vars = ids)

  output <- lapply(ids, function(index){
    table[, .(N=.N, min=min(value), max=max(value)), by=c("variable", index)] 
  })
  names(output) <- ids
  return(output)
} 

SummaryStat(tr, c("industry", "country"))
```

Comment: Ok I got the main idea, tried to do a simple function out of it.

    SummaryStat <- function(table, ratio, by){
      table <- melt(table, id.vars = by)
      table <- table[, .(N=.N, min=min(value), max=max(value)), by=.(variable, by)]
      return(table)
    }

    SummaryStat(tr,"rat1", "industry")

I get the error  Error in `[.data.table`(table, , .(N = .N, min = min(value), max = max(value)),  : 
  The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length (626674,1). Each must be same length as rows in x or number of rows returned by i (626674).

Comment: I'll edit my answer as a function. There is a more familiar syntax you can use for the by, it can take a named vector (see above)

Comment: Ok I have used your approach and it works more or less for all the fields I need, but what if I want to add to the frame the results of the quantile function?